# AppFabric DataCacheFactory() initialization hangs in VS2013, works fine in VS2010 and VS2012

Tags: c#, appfabric, visual-studio-2013, datacachefactory

I have an application that has been working for a while.  I tried running it with VS2013 and it hangs on a line where it tries to initialize a DataCacheFactory object.  The same code works fine with VS2010 and VS2012.

```
    private static DataCacheFactory GetDataCacheFactory()
    {
        if (factory == null)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                if (factory == null)
                {
                    factory = new DataCacheFactory();  //VS2013 hangs on this line
                }
            }
        }
        return factory;
    }
```

No errors are generated.  The code just hangs on the line `factory = new DataCacheFactory()`.

The AppFabric DLLs are current versions.

I welcome any suggestions for identifying why the code hangs on this line.

Comment: could you please describe your environment. Is it a remote cluster or a single host running on your machine ?

Comment: Could you attach windbg to your vshost & devenv processes, and print what ~*e!clrstack command yields (using sosex) ?

Comment: Or just attach another devenv to your running process, and see what threads are alive, and what they are doing/hanging on...

Comment: I am running the app in debug mode on my local box

Comment: I had a similar issue and resolved it: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967924/app-fabric-visual-studio-2013-issue/21181236][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967924/app-fabric-visual-studio-2013-issue/21181236

Comment: I checked the port.  I also tried changing it, but no luck.  Still hanging on that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue, but I don't know what was causing it.  I tried using DebugDiag to take a dump and analyze it.  The analysis indicated that the process was waiting for something to complete in a Compatibility module in some Microsoft code.

I noticed that there were two Compatibility Databases installed with IIS 8.  I uninstalled both items and tried running my app again.  This time the app successfully executed the line that was hanging.

While this resolved the issue on this machine, I still don't know what is causing the problem.  I have a colleague with a similar configuration and he has no problem with the app hanging on the line above, even with the Compatibility databases installed.

Answer (score 0):

As you are developing your app on VS, this might be a .net application. please check the targeted .net framework version from project properties when running on VS13.

Comment: The targeted .net framework is 4.0.  It is the same code that runs in VS 2010 and 2012, but hangs in 2013.

Comment: perform that operation on a try block and catch any exception.

    try
      {
          factory = new DataCacheFactory();
      }
      catch(//relevant exception )

Comment: I have tried the same code in a try/catch block, but that didn't yield anything as there was no exception.  The code is just hanging on this line.