# App Fabric Visual Studio 2013 Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, appfabric, appfabric-cache

I've upgraded my solution to work with VS2013. All builds fine.

However it seems to an issue with initialising AppFabric and it appears to be hanging on the line:

```
new DataCacheFactory();
```

The exact same code is working fine in VS2010 so it's completely thrown me!

Comment: @mcolegro did you ever rectify your similar issue? (http://stackoverflow.com/q/19688302/2220455)

Comment: What version of AppFabric? We have a VS2013 solution targeting [AppFabric Cumulative Update 4 for AppFabric 1.1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2800726) and it works just fine.

Comment: @stuartd Exactly the same as you. The same solution works for everyone else in my company apart from me!

Comment: @dhardy I think I have the same problem, any solutions?

Comment: Hi @TamimSalem - unfortunately not. I have to use VS2010. Please let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: couldn't fix yet, I added a bounty to @mcolegro's question, hope someone has a solution.

Comment: @TamimSalem are you using a remote AppFabric server or a local one? I'm using a remote one but I do have some remains from having previously ran it locally but could not completely uninstall it. I don't think this should affect it if it's set up as a remote server anyway...

Comment: @dhardy, i'm using a local one, in my personal case, i'm using the azure emulator to run a web and cache roles.

Comment: @TamimSalem - I have managed to resolve my issue. It was a strange but simple one. VS2013 switched my localhost port from 51725 to 2345. When I inspected IIS Express, it was using 51725. I then switched my web app to use port 51725 and now it all works.

Comment: @dhardy awesome! will try it out now.

Comment: Also note that I had to run VS2013 as administrator (right click > run as administrator) too

Comment: @dhardy - I have not been able to resolve this on my machine.  I was hoping the port fix would resolve it, but the port is not the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a hang dump of your client application when it is in a HUNG state using the Debug Diagnostic 2.0 tool (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40336) and then analyze the dump file by just double clicking the .dmp file and see the callstack of the thread that is hung while trying to create the DataCacheFactory ?

That will give an idea of where the thread is currently stuck at and should help in finding out the cause of the problem.

To collect a hang dump of the process you can just install the tool and open the tool and then click cancel on the "Rule Wizard" and go to the processes tab , find your client process and then choose **Create Full User Dump**

Comment: I created the dump and looked at it.  The only thing I could get from it was that one thread was waiting for another to finish.  I couldn't tell what the thread was waiting for.